# Minus 1 in Python query

Tags: python, list, find

when you have a code that includes

```
find list[7].find('~') == -1
    process
```

in this case, what does the -1 stand for?

I have attempted to change the numbers to different digits, but keep getting errors.

Answer (score 8):

`-1` is returned by `find()` when a particular substring is not found in a string, otherwise it returns the index of that substring. In your case `lis[7]` is a string and you're invoking `find()` on it.

```
In [23]: 'abc'.find('d')
Out[23]: -1

In [24]: 'abc'.find('b')
Out[24]: 1
```

**From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)**:

```
str.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int

    Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
    such that sub is contained within s[start:end].  Optional
    arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

    Return -1 on failure.
```

PS: Don't use `list` as a variable name

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

from the docs:

> str.find(sub[, start[, end]])¶
>
> Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found, such that sub is contained in the slice s[start:end]. Optional
>   arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. **Return
>   -1 if sub is not found.**